# Markdown error with link has character "_"

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

Content in markdown GitHub pages, for a real link: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server

```
Document: [https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)
```

Result

```html
<p>Document: [https://hub.docker.com/<em>/microsoft-mssql-server](https://hub.docker.com/</em>/microsoft-mssql-server)</p>
```

I catch this problem

[image]

then issue

[image]

https://donhuvy.github.io/sqlserver/docker/2020/10/12/microsoft-sql-server-2019-on-docker.html

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

In markdown, text surrounded by underscores is processed like emphasis and then surrounded by  tags.

If you want your underscores to be printed as is, you can escape them with a backslash "\".

```
Document: [https://hub.docker.com/\_/microsoft-mssql-server](https://hub.docker.com/\_/microsoft-mssql-server)
```

See [Kramdown syntax documentation](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#automatic-and-manual-escaping)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Document: [https://hub.docker.com/\_/microsoft-mssql-server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server)
```

Result: https://donhuvy.github.io/sqlserver/docker/2020/10/12/microsoft-sql-server-2019-on-docker.html